# What's the meaning of the assumption of "honest majority" in a mpc protocol? How to prove the security when (not) an honest majority assumption?

Tags: multiparty-computation, simulation

(1) What's the meaning of the assumption of "honest majority" in a mpc protocol?

(2) How to prove the security when (not) an honest majority assumption?

Comment: What's the relationship between an honest majority and  a semi-honest/malicious security assumption?

Comment: (1) "Honest majority" = adversary corrupts strictly less than $n/2$ out of $n$ parties. (2) Every protocol answers this question differently; the question needs more clarity. (3) They are orthogonal properties of a security model; one asks how many parties the adversary corrupts, and the other asks how those corrupt parties are allowed to behave.

Comment: @Mikero So does "an adversary can corrupt n/2 out of n parties" mean that the collision of n/2 parties out of n parties is allowed?

Comment: Honest majority = **strict** honest majority. Strictly less than half are corrupt.

Comment: @Mikero Yes, you are right! What I am confused about is the relationship between the honest majority and the collision of parties. The honest majority implies how many parties are allowed to collude?  Still strictly less than half?

Comment: @Mikero So are there any recommended articles about this?